# Check for column's character set and collation in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Is there a way to check if a certain MySQL column has a specific character set and collation  with JDBC?

For those who need some background informations: The application I am working has changed its database layout with new versions. The update mechanisms was implemented rather basic: during startup, the application checks if the change is already there and, if not, alters the table accordingly. Right now I need to change an existing column to be unique and case sensitive (which means, I need to change the column's character-set and collation accordingly).

Comment: May be table META information call to get that info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to query it from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. The `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` and `COLLATION_NAME` fields are what you need.

There is nothing in the JDBC spec that provides access to this.